# Is there any complete specification of the transactions?

Tags: transactions

I see the wiki page [Script](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script), and the page on [Contracts](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Contracts) makes some remarks on things like signature numbers and SIGHASH flags, but it seems incomplete and not very friendly to someone not familiar with the protocol. **Is there an official specification of the transaction protocol** other than the wiki pages? Or do I have to read the source code?

Comment: Is there an update to this question, or has there been any movement within the community to draft a network specification for Bitcoin?  I think this is quite necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Or do I have to read the source code?

This is the only "official specification". The wiki pages have a lot of good info, but they sometimes contain inaccuracies or important omissions.

There's some info about the SIGHASH flags here:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/OP_CHECKSIG